# I can not bind the global IP address to the socket

Tags: php, sockets, networking, tcp

Of course, I have a server-side client application, the IP is bound to the server via bind.

Over time, the development of some applications on PHP sockets, using the TCP protocol, using the open port 5555 in the local system, the problem was not working, that is, the application worked with each other, on the internal Ip 127.0.0.1, then there was a test for 0.0 .0.0 everything is just as good, after all, decided to potestit on two different hosts, started with a local network WI-FI still just worked fine. 
But when I came to the global system, I wanted the client and the server to work through a global network, namely the client accessed the server over the global IP. Accordingly, I must bind to the server, bind global IP, but in the end I get an error that it did not work out to bind the data 10049, but I left the port the same. I've tried many ways, to do port forwarding on the router, opening the port in the system, and much more, in the end nothing. Global Ip I take with 2ip. Can anyone come across this, I will note only that it is higher than the language, because such a mistake was also in Pythonists. Maybe someone knows something, thank you. P.S interpreter is taken from the site, version 7.1, the application uses the CLI module, respectively, not a web browser, no web server is used.
P.S.S sorry for my bad English, I just use an interpreter, because I do not know much English.

`$address = '95.46.122.65'; $port = 5555; socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP) $ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);`

Comment: Are you behind a NAT router? You can't bind to the public address of the router, you have to configure port forwarding on the router and bind to the private address of the server.

Comment: I configured the re-routing of external requests to port 5555 on the router, it did not help.

Comment: What address did you bind to on in the Python code?

Comment: I'm working on PHP, connected the global IP of the network interface.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: К сожалению или к счастью, код не сложный `$ address = '95 .46.122.65 '; $ port = 5555; socket_create (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) $ ret = socket_bind ($ sock, $ address, $ port); `

Comment: Post the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Didn't you see what I said above? You should be binding to the private IP, not the public IP.

Comment: Then I do not understand something? With local IP, it works for me, does not work with the global one, if I make the re-routing of the global IP to the local IP, at the same time I bind the local IP, then how do I distribute my application? Users will have to do the same.

Comment: The application should bind to `INADDR_ANY`, which listens on all local addresses. They'll need to do port forwarding in their routers.

Comment: And this can not be avoided in any way? Problems in NAT router?

Comment: Do you even know what NAT does? Because then you would understand why to insert a Privat IP!

Comment: Well, if I do a re-routing, on a router from port 5555, to a local address, at the same time I tie a global one, it will not work?

Comment: The server doesn't know anything about the public IP. The router performs the translation, so the server sees the connection coming to its private IP. You need to learn how NAT works.

Comment: OK thank you very much!